# NASSCO PACP Schema Standard and CCTV Processor from ArcGIS for Utilities?

Tags: arcgis-water-utilities, cctv, nassco

I'm using the [ESRI CCTV processor](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/cctv-processor/) from ArcGIS for Utilities.

I received data from the contractors and when trying to use the ESRI PACP_schema.xml sample there were some issues with field name differences and data types (See image below).

Is anyone familiar with the NASSCO standards or know where to find the current NASSCO schema standard?

[image]

Comment: I've been in touch with ESRI about this and they found that there is something wrong with the tool and the Schema they are using and are working on updating it.

Comment: OP did you find a reference to find the schema and codes for this standard?

Comment: @Geo.Dude Found a copy of the PACP Codes in the NASSCO Manual the codes can be found in there in the appendix, we then programed them into a set of sql queries to run one the PACP Database to attach the codes [EDIT] (As per the schema newer version of data we received were correct)